# email validation in input field

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, css, html5

i have a login box. While entering email then the box outline should be red and once a valid email address is entered then the box outline should automatically change to green.
How to achive this in aura component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base lightning:input component can validate email address formats.

See the example in the Lightning Component Library:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleInputEmail

Comment: Does this work for multiple email addresses at once? if not do you have a suggestion on what's the best route to go for that?